# Html z-index not provident specification

Tags: html, css, layout, z-index, w3c

Looking at the CSS specification of the W3C and observing the rendering of my own solution I have come to only one conclusion:
If I have dialog window (absolutely positioned) with an input field (relative) in it and usual autocompleter script (usual includes ul list beyond input (absolutely pos.)) - I can't make a dropdown list of autocomplete values visible normally and place it over buttons and borders of parent dialog window?
It’s make me feel bad.
Can any one debunk this regrettable result?

Sorry for my English.

**upd2:**

```
        <div id="modal-window" style="display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 9000; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; left: 530px; top: -58px;">
            <div id="modal-window-body">
                <input id="city" name="city" />
                <ul class="autocompleter-choices" style="position:absolute; z-index: 19999; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; left: 8px; top: 406px; width: 126px; overflow-y: scroll; height: 189px;">
                    <li class="autocompleter-selected">
                        <span class="autocompleter-queried">
                            N
                        </span>
                        amibia
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="modal-window-buttons">
                    <span class="button">
                        <a href="#" class="button-ok">ok</a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="button">
                        <a href="#" class="button-close">cancel</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

result:

[image]

Принимаю ответы на русском языке так же. Очень неприятная загвоздка вышла. Надо решить.

Comment: How this works will depend on your HTML/CSS structure. Without an example, it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 2):

z-index can only be given to positioned elements. Your ul class="autocompleter-choices" seems not to be positioned (if it's true that you're only using inline styles in this doc). Try to position it absolute or relative.

Comment: Sorry. There is(!) absolute positioning to **ul.autocompleter-choices**. Shame on me - I forgot to paste it on.

Comment: look at windowshot. it's impossible to do such thing without abs pos.

Comment: @Lazy, to be fair, this answer was posted before you updated your question to actually include such a shot and the HTML. However, even with just the shot, it only confirms that the modal has positioning, not that the autocomplete does.

Comment: yes. i have no reasons to make your confusion. sorry if i had. anyway, if autocomplete will have relative or static(inherit) position property - modal window will stretch to size of autocomplete list. but it hasn't.

Answer (score 1):

My only guess, based on the minimal information given, is that `#modal-window-body` has a specified `height` and `overflow:hidden`. This explains why it never fully shows and the biggest part of your problem. However, it doesn't explain why it falls under the buttons. Again, my guess is `#modal-window-buttons` is `position: absolute; bottom:0; z-index: higher-that-yours`.

I would expand your question to include more information than the inline styles applied during javascript manipulation. Only knowing the current state of the css can we assist further.

Comment: @Lazy, no you have. Your last edit was 16 minutes ago, while my post is only 4 minutes old.

Comment: 1. `#modal-window-body` realy don't have specified height and have no specified overflow (i.e. no hidden). 2. I don't need to stretch modal window, autocomplete has to be over buttons and border. It implies that position of ul must be absolute and it is. 3. buttons of modal window have relative position and `z-index` lower than `ul.autocompleter-choices`